# PHP SQL Query Fails to Execute

Tags: php, mysql, sql, web

```
<?php
$db = new mysqli("localhost", "HIDDEN", "HIDDEN", "HIDDEN");
if ($db->connect_error) {
    die("Failed to connect.");
}
if (isset($_POST["title"]) && isset($_POST["description"]) && isset($_POST["url"])) {
    $title = $db->real_escape_string($_POST["title"]);
    $description = $db->real_escape_string($_POST["description"]);
    $url = $db->real_escape_string($_POST["url"]);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO video (name, description, submission_date)
    VALUES ('{$title}', '{$description}', CURDATE());
    INSERT INTO video_source (video_id, url)
    VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(), '{$url}');";
    if ($db->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo "Successfully added.";
    } else {
        echo "Query failed.<br><br>Data: {$title} {$description} {$url}";
    }
} else {
    echo "Data not set.";
}
$db->close();?>
```

Outputs "Query failed." with the data I entered. Replacing variables such as title with constants still has the same problem. I tried the query in PHPMyAdmin and it worked fine (with constants).

It seems to be unhappy with setting the value of video_id.

Comment: Your missing " after localhost

Comment: When localhost is properly enclosed in quotes the code still outputs the same error.

Comment: You're attempting to run two queries, which one fails?

Comment: Second one, when I remove video_id from it, it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anytime you're running multiple queries with MySQLi you should use [`multi_query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php):

```
$db->multi_query($sql)
```

In addition, `LAST_INSERT_ID()` in your second query is not  returning any sort of value. If you're looking for the last inserted value of the 1st query you have to return that prior to running the second query.

Comment: That worked, thank you :) Oddly enough when I just used the second query with only constants it still didn't work :/